Meaning of this Eisenstein series notation from Gross–Zagier paper
In equation (2.14) of their paper [1], Gross–Zagier define the following Eisenstein series
\begin{align}
E_N(z, s) = \sum_{\gamma \in \bigg(\begin{matrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{matrix}\bigg) \backslash \Gamma_0(N)}
\textrm{Im}(\gamma z)^s.
\end{align}
I would like to know what is meant by the notation
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\ast & \ast \\
0 & \ast
\end{pmatrix}
\backslash \Gamma_0(N)
\end{align}
in the summation.
I was thinking maybe it refers to the quotient of $\Gamma_0(N)$ by the normal closure (maybe unnecessary) of the subgroup generated by $-I_2$ (identity matrix) and the matrix
\begin{align}
T =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
So the summation is over a set of right coset representatives.
Edit: I suppose I should say that my question is not so much what the $A \backslash B$ notations means, but rather what is meant by
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\ast & \ast \\
0 & \ast
\end{pmatrix}
.
\end{align}
The meaning of $A \backslash B$ will then be clear (although I doubt that it means set difference because not everything in $\Gamma_0(N)$ has a zero in the lower left entry). Also it probably doesn't mean upper triangular matrices in $M_2(\mathbf{Z})$, because this set is not stable under $\Gamma_0(N)$.
[1] Gross, Benedict H.; Zagier, Don B., Heegner points and derivatives of (L)-series, Invent. Math. 84, 225-320 (1986). ZBL0608.14019.

In this case, we have
$$ \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & * \end{pmatrix} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_0(N) : a, b, d \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}.$$
That is, the stars mean any integer and implicitly are restricted to be a subgroup of $\Gamma_0(N)$ so that the quotient makes sense.
A different notation that is more common now is $\Gamma_\infty$ (where $\Gamma$ is implicitly $\Gamma_0(N)$), which stands for the stabilizer of $\infty$ under the action of $\Gamma_0(N)$. Yet another name that is more common now is the maximal parabolic subgroup of $\Gamma_0(N)$.

Thanks very much, David!
